# How to write curl get request on python to decrease parsing time

Tags: php, python, curl

I have basic curl GET request to work with site API in php:

```
$headers = array(
  "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"windows-1251\"",
  "Host:api.content.com",
  "Accept:*/*",
  "Authorization:qwerty"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.content.com/v1.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$f = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

#echo $data;
$total = $f['total'];
curl_close($ch);
}
```

What is the best way to write this in python in case, that this request will be used in separate subprocesses to decrease parsing time?

Comment: You can look at requests module.

Comment: It looks nice, can you post an example? Im not so good in python

Comment: if there is true answer you should close the question; click to set that answer as your accepted answer. @user1835337

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), from requests document;

```
>>> import json
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>>> headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use any of the following module:

- `urllib2` (its in python by default)
- `requests` (you need to install)

Example:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://example.com/')
>>> print r.text
.
.
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com')
>>> print response.info()
.
.
>>> html = response.read()
>>> print html
.
.
```

Comment: How to pass a variable inside `headers = {'Authorization': <variable_name>}` ?